# ESD SPI/ISP bus protection

Tags: digital-logic, spi, protection, esd, isp

I am designing a board based on the Atmega328P microcontroller. For this controller there is an ISP connector for programming.
This connector has the following pins: MOSI / MISO / RST / SCK.

There is a task to protect this tire from electrostatic discharges.

To protect IO / I2C / UART, I use [NUP4114](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUP4114-D.PDF).

Scheme:

[image]

[image]

It is designed to protect several IOs simultaneously.

**Question:** Is using the NUP4144 in the circuit above suitable for ISP / SPI line?

Comment: It is suitable for any speed of 5V logic

Comment: Is it possible to use on 3.3V logic?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 "Any speed of 5V logic" could be misleading. We could agree on that NUP4114 is suitable for the proposed application (ISP Programming of ATMEGA328P)

Comment: Yes, you can use the NUP4114 for 3.3V logic.

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/circuit-protection/tvs-diodes/144?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv1731=908&pv1731=732&pv1731=714&pv1731=336&pv1731=337&pv1731=724&sf=1&FV=ffe00090&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: What is "ISP"? If it is SPI, then call it SPI.

Comment: Anyway, you could just connect 4 low ohm resistors in series with the signals near the connector.

Comment: whether this connector has any VCC connected for programming? is that vcc available always or switched by some logic(like only during programming)

Comment: user19579, VCC is always available

Comment: @Lundin ATmega ISP is *similar* to SPI and in many cases uses a target processor's SPI pins and may be implemented with an SPI engine in the programmer, but it is not really SPI.

Comment: @ChrisStratton SPI isn't standardized though. And it is annoying that every MCU manufacturer must come up with their own private mumbo jumbo name for it.

Comment: It's not a private mumbo-jumbo name for SPI.   The parts do implement SPI for normal SPI purposes, this is distinct, but electrically similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUP4114 has very low capacitance, in the 0.3pf range. It also shows that the NUP4114 working on differential lines at 500Mhz. Since SPI, I2C and Uarts don't operate at this speed, it's safe to say that the NUP4114 would not affect signals under 100MHz and would be fine for what you described.

The GPIO capacitance of most microprocessors is much higher, usually 10x higher, so I wouldn't worry about adding this part to digital lines of low speed (under 50MHz).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!